# How to unpack a list inside placeholder { } in python

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have a list of strings, name, ignore_stock. I want to display it in a telegram bot message. Presently,  I am displaying it like this:

```
update.message.reply_text(f'<b>Following stocks are ignored: {ignore_stock}</b>', parse_mode='HTML')
```

This displays the list like this: ['a','b','c'] inside the telegram bot message.

I want to display the list like this: a, b, c inside the telegram bot message without [ ] and ''. How do I do that?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is type of `ignore_stock`?

Comment: a list of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `{ignore_stock}` with `{",".join(ignore_stock)}`